# É possível salvar uma imagem com a biblioteca Imagine PHP sem fazer a compactação do tamanho dela?

Tags: php, imagem, upload

Estou usando a biblioteca Imagine PHP para fazer o upload e tratamento de imagens e quando eu vou realizar o upload de imagens do tipo .GIF ele faz isso normalmente mantendo as dimensões da imagem original mas ele faz a compactação do tamanho da mesma, com isso a imagem .GIF perde a sua 'animação' tornando-se como se fosse uma imagem normal. Eu revirei a [documentação deles](https://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/layers.html#animated-gif-frame-manipulation) mas não consegui nada que pudesse me ajudar. Na hora de salvar a imagem eu tentei passar alguns parâmetros alistados na documentação, mas não obtive sucesso:

```
$image->save('cats.gif', Array('quality' => 100, 'animated' => TRUE, 'flatten' => FALSE));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pelo que vi na documentação, é necessário iterar pela imagem, pois a biblioteca vai iterar por cada layers (frames). no link que vc mesmo postou ele fazem o redimensionamento com um `foreach ($image->layers() as $frame) {
    $frame->resize(new Box(100, 100));
}
`

Comment: @RenatoTavares tentei isso mas não rolou... o que ocorre é que depois que ele salva a imagem é feita a compactação do tamanho da mesma. Estou anexando uma imagem na pergunta para você ver o que estou falando

Comment: Nunca usei essa biblioteca mas, lendo superficialmente o link da documentação, tem um exemplo que mostra o método `coalesce()`. Tente invocar esse método antes de invocar o método `save()`. Exemplo: `$image->layers()->coalesce();`.

Comment: @DanielOmine já tentei usar isso mas também não funcionou

Comment: Você quer compactar as imagens mantendo o mais alto nível de qualidade possível e manter inalterado as dimensões, certo?

Comment: E obviamente, para imagens gif animadas, manter todos os layers.

Comment: @DanielOmine na real eu quero que ela mantenha o tamanho e dimensões originais. As dimensões originais eu to conseguindo manter mas o tamanho não. Como ela está sendo compactada no tamanho o GIF deixa de funcionar

Comment: Suspeitei que quisesse isso mas evitei comentar. O que eu iria comentar é, se não precisa compactar ou mexer nas dimensões, então não precisa de library alguma. Apenas faça o upload normalmente resgatando do global `$_FILES`. Então usaria o `move_uploaded_file` ou `copy()`.

Comment: Realmente @DanielOmine essa foi a unica alternativa que me restou. Utilizei o Copy e deu certo. Obrigado!